# Is there a hotkey to switch between tabs in the default terminal app?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Is there a hotkey to switch between tabs in Ubuntu's native terminal app? I'm using the netbook version of ubuntu.

Comment: Too bad the hotkey isn't ctrl+tab. I wonder if it can be changed.

Comment: yes you can change it @pinouchon, see my answer below (unfortunately ctrl+tab wont work)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to efficiently switch between several terminal windows using the keyboard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423529/how-to-efficiently-switch-between-several-terminal-windows-using-the-keyboard)

Answer (score 184):

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd> to go to previous/next tab.

Comment: I had to use CTRL+SHIFT+ PgUp / PgDn

Comment: not cool. Mac doesn't have it.

Comment: @Vlad on my macbook it appears to be CMD+SHIFT+LEFT_ARROW/RIGHT_ARROW, maybe that works for you as well.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with numpad PgUp / PgDn keys I typically use on my laptop, but the dedicated PgUp / PgDn keys do work. I was able to edit the shortcuts to use the numpad easily, as described below :)

Comment: For me ctrl + function + up/down works

Answer (score 73):

You mean `gnome-terminal`?

To switch between tabs you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>**n**</kbd>, where **n** is the tab ordinal number.

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Maj</kbd>+<kbd>**n**</kbd> if using an azerty keyboard, caps-locked or not...

By the way, this works the same in Gedit.

Comment: And it also works in Chromium, I just found out!

Answer (score 16):

I'm guessing you mean the default distributed (pre-installed) gnome-terminal.

You can set your own shortcuts easily, just go to menu `Edit>Keyboard Shortcuts...`

[image: gnome-terminal keyboard shortcuts settings as seen on ubuntu 12.04]

**Bonus tip**: If you wanna take a look to the real "native terminal" or tty (teletype interfase) just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (It works with almost any Function key), and don't panic, you can come back to the "graphical interfase" by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

Comment: Is it any way to set them to Ctrl+Shift+Tab and Ctrl+Tab?

Answer (score 8):

Simple and standard for all:

**for switching/moving tabs:**

```
Ctrl + pg up
```

or

```
Ctrl + pg dn
```

**for positioning tabs (not switching):**

if you want to position tabs, but not switch/move. is useful when too many tabs are open in web browser and or terminal and you want to group/lineup tabs. you can do this.

```
CtrlShift + pg up
```

or

```
CtrlShift + pg dn
```

**Pro Tip:**

try this in your browser tabs. and see what happens.

Comment: This has started inserting `;5~` for me lately instead of switching tabs. Any idea what would cause that?

Comment: it does happens when a process you or some other application started did not left the terminal and while you press other keys it prints some odd characters.

Comment: This works in some Editor too, e.g `Geany`. The switch also works in `IDEA`, though positioning doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone using Konsole, that comes with Kubuntu (or KDE), the shortcut is -

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this answer! It deserve more upvotes

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>, where n is the tab number starting from 1, works for me on Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome Desktop Environment.

Answer (score 0):

For the MacBook Pro (I suppose it's the same with other macs) running Ubuntu on VMWare there are two options:

1. With the large Apple Magic Keyboard with Numeric Keypad, use the **arrows below F15** (don't know their official names, but I now believe they're the Page Up/Down keys already mentioned) with **CTRL**, but **not** the regular cursor/arrow keys at the bottom of the keyboard:

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>

2. With the built-in laptop keyboard *or* with the external keyboard use the **function** key, plus **control**, plus the regular **up/down** keys:

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>

In other words, option 2 should work in all cases, but if you have the large keyboard there's an additional convenient shortcut.

By the way, both options also allow switching between Google Chrome and Opera tabs. Haven't tested with Firefox yet.