# How to efficiently switch between several terminal windows using the keyboard?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> lets me only switch between windows belonging to different applications.

I often use about four terminal bound applications at the same time (e.g. IPython, VIM, fish for system and fish for git).

Even using the mouse, clicking the terminal icon on the launcher being offered takes time to decide which is which. But I don't know so far any way to switch in this case using my keyboard only.

How to handle multiple terminals (and instances of same application in general) efficiently using the keyboard?

With respect to the terminal special case - is there a terminal application allowing sperate terminals in tabs?

---

And the Oscar goes to ...

tmux

Comment: You can try **Tiling window manager**, such as i3wm. In i3 it is able to chnage window focus with $mod+hijk.

Comment: Define "efficiently"?

Comment: @Braiam: "efficiently" as in "Ubuntu reads my mind in speed of light, switches to the terminal I want to use and serves me coffee in case my awakeness level fell below 70%"

Comment: Instead of separate terminal windows, I'd learn tmux and create multiple windows and panes in a single terminal. It's fast, and customizable and scriptable to your hearts content.

Comment: @Philip: Aye, aye, Sir ... installed tmux and it's great!

Comment: Just to add this: Super+W is switching between all your open windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [keyboard shortcut to switch between windows within an application](http://askubuntu.com/questions/372398/keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-between-windows-within-an-application)

Comment: You might consider using `screen`...

Answer (score 129, accepted):

In linux almost every terminal support tab, for example in Ubuntu with default terminal you can press:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> or click File / Open Tab
2. and you can switch between them using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>$ {tab_number}</kbd> (*eg. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>)

also you might want to take a look at [terminator](http://lifehacker.com/5858676/the-best-terminal-emulator-for-linux)

Comment: Perhaps better to talk about Ubuntu alone because xterm doesn't do tabs. And that counts a lot.

Comment: I know, that's why I've said - almost every terminal :)

Comment: @progo It's not specific to Ubuntu, it's supported at least in `gnome-terminal`, `konsole` and several other widely-used terminals. AFAIK, `gnome-terminal` is default terminal in Ubuntu.

Comment: not in xfce... does not work for Xubuntu...

Comment: This does not answer the question. Tabs are useful, of course, but many uses cases for multiple windows (for example, iteratively running and editing code) requires being able to see the contents of both terminals at once.

Comment: well, Terminator (as specified in answer) can help you achieve that

Comment: `alt+tab number` did not work for me, ubuntu 22.04. `ctrl+page up/page down` working okay

Answer (score 104):

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>tilde</kbd> (<kbd>tilde</kbd> = <kbd>Grave</kbd>) to switch between windows of the current application. Note that <kbd>tilde</kbd> is always the key above tab, it is a tilde in an US english keyboard, but it can be anything in other languages.

If you press the Windows key for a while unity will show you all it's keyboard shortcuts in an overlay:

[image]

Finally, near all terminal applications support tabs. The default one in Ubuntu does.

Comment: This is the most intuitive answer, I think. I use this all the time.

Comment: The key above tab is tilde on (presumably) **US** English keyboards, it certainly is.;t with an en-GB keyboard layout.

Comment: This is not working for me at all. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 installed on a MacBook Air, if that helps. Alt-Tab works, Alt-Tilde does not.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: The thing I don't like about `ALT+~` is that you don't know the order it will switch to because the first press will jump to the most recent window, then it cycles through the rest of the windows. I wish there was the similar jumping shortcuts they have for tabs.

Comment: ALT + ~ can switch the same windows

Answer (score 40):

Have you Tried to open multiple terminals using:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Then switching among them using:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PageUP</kbd>

And

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PageDown</kbd>

I usually use this scenario at least for me

Comment: That is multiple tabs of one window , actually

Comment: @Xieerqi Yes I know and it is the same as the accepted answer but I don't know why I didn't get an upvote at least

Comment: Well, like I said - this answer is just related to one window, and user wanted switching between multiple windows so it makes some sense why your answer is ignored. I use this method all the time, though, so IMHO it's alright,too.

Comment: in my case I had to put in a 'fn' to make above work but that won't be the case for every system

Comment: Thank goodness for this answer.

Answer (score 14):

Not the answer you are looking for, but I think it's worth considering:
Instead of multiple tabs, you can use `screen` and `byobu`:
[image]

`screen` lets you manage multiple terminals in the same window. In the previous image you can see I have 3 terminals (0 tcpdump, 1 top and 2 Node.js). You can switch between them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>`{index of the terminal}`</kbd> for example (there are a lot of commands).
`byobu` is a wrapper for `screen`, it adds some color, more commands and a help menu. But you can use `screen` alone, without `byobu`.
Here there is a tutorial on how to install and use `screen` and `byobu`:

- [How to Install and Use Screen on an Ubuntu Cloud Server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-use-screen-on-an-ubuntu-cloud-server)

Comment: If I may, I'll also add, that byobu works in tty consoles as well as in graphical environment. So useful, much indicators, wow !

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> i.e. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tilde</kbd>allows you to switch between the windows of the same application.

Or you can organize those windows in different workspaces and use the keyboard shortcuts to go to the proper workspace; I have four workspaces and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> to switch between them. This could comparatively prove to be a faster way to go to the right application window when you have quite a few to handle.<sub>[You can specify the number of workspace to be used in your system.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34572/how-can-i-reduce-or-increase-the-number-of-workspaces-in-unity)</sub>

To swap the windows between the workspaces I use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>.

---

These are some terminal emulators that allow multiple tab feature:

- [konsole](http://konsole.kde.org/)
- [guake](https://github.com/Guake/guake)
- [yakuake](http://extragear.kde.org/apps/yakuake/)

[image: yakuakeSnap]

Answer (score 5):

In KDE it is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>: System Settings → Workspace Appearance and Behavior → Window Behavior :

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to try out **[Guake](https://github.com/Guake/guake/)**, which can be installed from the software center

`sudo apt-get install guake`

Here's a screenshot

[image]

I personally switch tabs by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page down</kbd>, which is also the default as far as I remember.

Also I've bound Guake to the `menu` button, which I always considered useless. Now I can toggle the terminal with a single button and feel like I have super powers.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new terminal window:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>

Create a new terminal tab:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

Close a single terminal tab or window:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>

Switch between terminal windows:
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>`</kbd>

Switch between terminal tabs:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Page down</kbd> (left), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page up</kbd> (right), or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd>, e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Raffael asked:

> is there a terminal application allowing seperate terminals in tabs?

I really like **konsole** for that.

Keyboard Shortcuts (which also can be changed!)

New Tab

- STRG + Shift + **T**

Change Tab

- Shift + Left / Right

Move Tab

- STRG + Change Tab

Close Tab

- Type 'exit' as often as you need or STRG + Shift + **W**

You can also split view (vertically or horizontally)

- STRG + **(**  or **)**  (means for me STRG + Shift + 8 or 9)

and close split view

- STRG + Shift + **S**

And try it together with **[Gnome Extension Putwindows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/)**

Answer (score 1):

Switch between open instances of one program:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

Switch between open tabs of one program instance:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Switch between programs:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I've found `alt` + `f6` works as well. This can also be changed to whatever keyboard shortcut you wish in settings by navigating to settings>devices>keyboard and scrolling to the shortcut: Switch windows of an app directly, found under the navigation heading.

Answer (score 0):

Simply hold Alt (after releasing Tab and choosing CLI window(s)) a bit longer and you will get opportunity to choose between multiple CLI windows...

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to use xterm as wrapper. As much as I like grouping feature sometimes a window better to be ungrouped. I.e. I use midnight commander as a file manager and it goes grouped with other terminal windows which is not nice

So what I did is:

1. leave gnome-terminal as default terminal app
2. edit */usr/share/applications/mc.desktop* to execute mc within xterm session `Exec=xterm  -geometry 152x42 -fa 'Monospace' -fs 19  -T "Midnight Commander" -n "Midnight Commander" -e mc`

You can do something like this to your app. Having it wrapped to xterm makes it to be put to separate group under alt-tab. Its not a flawless solution, you'll need to deal with colour scheme, copying to buffer may give you a troble, but generally its an ok workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Following commands will help you a lot:

Create new terminal window in user directory: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Create new terminal window in current working directory: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

Create new terminal tab in current working directory:<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Minimize a terminal window or (any open window) : <kbd>super(window key)</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

Switch between windows of different apps: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>

Switch between windows of terminal(windows of current open app): <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>tilde</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick that I use:

1. Install two (or more) different terminal applications and put both of them into your favourite activities list (the list on the left side of your screen). Put them at the top so that they would get assigned numbers 1 and 2:

[image]

2. Pressing `windows` + `1` / `windows` + `2` will let you switch between the first / second terminal applications.

In this way, you can shift between console screens using a keyboard without losing the view of the previous one.